# Problem related to 'pvlib' module to get POA on a vertical surface in Northern Hemisphere

Tags: python, pandas, timezone-offset, pvlib, solar

So I am working on a project to identify the total irradiance falling on vertical walls oriented towards East, South, North and West. I am encountering a problem where the code produces very high irradiance on Eastern wall than the Southern Wall. This cannot be true since the Southern oriented walls should receive the highest irradiance.

```
import pandas as pd
import pvlib
import matplotlib as plt

tmy = pd.read_csv('Weatherfile_0.5_Ed.csv',nrows = 8760, usecols=["DHI","DNI","GHI"])
tmy.index = pd.date_range(start="2023-01-01 00:00", end="2023-12-31 23:00", freq='h',tz="US/Mountain")


location = pvlib.location.Location(latitude=53.5501,longitude=-113.469,tz='Etc/GMT+6')
times = tmy.index-pd.Timedelta('30min')
solar_position_ed = location.get_solarposition(times)
solar_position_ed.index += pd.Timedelta('30min')
df_poa_ed = pvlib.irradiance.get_total_irradiance(
    surface_tilt=90, 
    surface_azimuth=180,dni=tmy['DNI'],ghi=tmy['GHI'],dhi=tmy['DHI'],solar_zenith=solar_position_ed['apparent_zenith'],
    solar_azimuth=solar_position_ed['azimuth'],
    model='isotropic')


df_poa_ed.plot()
```

I tried making the tmy file timezone aware and also changed the tz parameter. Yet, my code shows high irradiance on the eastern wall compared to southern wall.

[South Wall:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lJnw.png)

It is inconsistent since it shows lower irradiance during summer

[East Wall:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhVfI.png)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is incorrect?  Try different tilt angles, for example 0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90 to see how the patterns change.  A vertical surface benefits when the sun is low in the sky, which happens in the morning and in winter.